# GeForce GTX 1070 - hashrate only 680 khash/s?

Tags: mining, gpu

I am mining ArtByte and LiteCoin using a single GTX 1070 GPU. Everywhere on the internet I am reading that such a card can achieve 20+ MH/s. My card only gets as far as 680 khash/s. Am I missing something? How to investigate this issue?

For ArtByte I am using:

> cudaminer 2014-02-28 (beta).

For LiteCoin:

> ccminer 2.1 for nVidia GPUs by tpruvot@github ***
>   Built with VC++ 2013 and nVidia CUDA SDK 8.0 64-bits

BR, Rene

Answer (score 0):

20MH/s for the GTX 1070 sounds like Ethereum hashrate. 680KH/s for Litecoin seems reasonable and no idea about ArtByte but it sounds like another obscure altcoin. You are posting on the Ethereum forum after all.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Meanwhile I am a bit more "literate" in crypto coins and learned they are all indeed very different. 680 KH/s I achieved indeed for LiteCoin. Initially I thought that hashrate was a sort of standardized unit of measurement which would be the same for all coins. Meanwhile I learned that for each combination of hardware and coin we have a different maximum achievable hashrate. So - for example - reported hashrates for ETH cannot be compared to hashrates for LiteCoin.